# Mysterious anonymous function in Dart

Tags: dart, syntax, anonymous-function

I know the usage of anonymous function with `() {}` but what `() {}()` mean?
I'm using it in a Text widget like this:

```
new Text(
  () {
    return "hello";
  }(),
),
```

It works pretty well but why do I need to add `()` after the anonymous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the second set of parentheses, you're just declaring an anonymous function, nothing else. So without that second set, you would be passing a function *reference* to the `Text` widget.

Now when you add the second set of parentheses you're actually *calling* the function that you defined.

If you look at it another way it might make it more clear. If you give that anonymous function a name you'll get the same result.

```dart
Function test = () {
  return "hello";
};
  
print(test());
```

is equivalent to

```dart
print(() {
    return "hello";
  }());
```